# footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a page into my site where I want that the footer stay on the bottom of the page when I scroll down the page the footer is every time on the bottom of the page.
And now when I scroll down the footer remain at the same position and don't go on the bottom of the page
I don't know if the problem is the backstretch plugin maked in jquery but this is my code:

```
<title>Atec Clima</title>
<script>
    $.backstretch("img/bg.jpg",{speed: 500});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <?php require("_header.php");?>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="riquadri">
            <img src="img/home/riscaldamento.jpg" alt="riscaldamento" />
            <p>
                Una caldaia ben mantenuta consuma meno… risparmia energia e dura di pi&ugrave;!!<br />
Una  caldaia periodicamente controllata &egrave; garanzia di sicurezza per l’utente e per l’ambiente. 
            <title>Atec Clima</title>
<script>
    $.backstretch("img/bg.jpg",{speed: 500});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <?php require("_header.php");?>
    <div class="page">


    </div>

</div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

body  {
    font-family: UbuntuRegular;
    font-size: 62.8%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff url(../img/bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;
}
.container {
    width: 1000px; 
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto -140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 2;
    padding-bottom:140px;
}

.footer{
    background:#1357c6;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:140px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem. Here is a nice, well-known, cross-browser solution:

[Make the Footer Stick to the Bottom of a Page](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)